# img src doesnt show in cordova app although it works in browser

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap

Hello I have an image url, when I try to open in browser it works but when I try to open from mobile app it doesn't work.

```
<img src="http://83.66.137.45/hys/e-ticaret/cms/File/Get?fileNameWithExtension=p2.jpg&extendedPath=Product"  />
```

I couldnt understand anything from problem. Because there is no error but img doesnt work . How can I solve problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just added your image to one of my recent projects and it does work (for me):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HvDB.png

Comment: You have to make sure that your phone has a internet connection though